# Use わけで at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar

「しかし、そうはいっても少し寂しくはありますな。やはり男たる者、空飛ぶ機動戦艦で任務をこなすという矜恃に勝るものはない**わけで**！<フラクシナス>には一刻も早く戦線復帰してもらいたいものでござりますな！」

I have simple question. I know the わけで is used to explain some reason. But why not use わけだ? Why is the sentence end with わけで? What is this grammar phenomenon?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I feel like the writer is using the exclamation point here to emphasize the first part of the sentence, not to actually complete the sentence if that makes sense. Where is this from?

Comment: @Mac Thanks for the response. It’s from a light novel named “date a live”.